# <select> list increasing height

Tags: html, css

I' m facing a doubt about using select/options in a mobile page.
After I added a list, openable with a button, the page increases height even without the activation of the list view.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I chosen to use the jquery css to make tests.

Here's the list code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="titulo">Nova O.S.</div>

    <div id="novaos">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">

            <input type="text" name="placa" placeholder="Placa"/>

            <div class="subtitulo">ACESSORIOS 01</div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                    <option value="aces01" name="aces01" id="aces01">3 EIXO</option>
                    <option value="aces02" name="aces02" id="aces02">CHAVE DE RODA OK</option>
                    <option value="aces03" name="aces03" id="aces03">ESTEPE OK</option>
                    <option value="aces04" name="aces04" id="aces04">EXTINTOR OK</option>
                    <option value="aces05" name="aces05" id="aces05">MACACO OK</option>
                    <option value="aces06" name="aces06" id="aces06">PNEUS BONS</option>
                    <option value="aces07" name="aces07" id="aces07">PNEUS LISOS</option>
                    <option value="aces08" name="aces08" id="aces08">PNEUS REGULARES</option>
                    <option value="aces09" name="aces09" id="aces09">RASTREADOR</option>
                    <option value="aces10" name="aces10" id="aces10">TACOGRAFO</option>
                    <option value="aces11" name="aces11" id="aces11">TRIANGULO OK</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="salvar" value="PRÓXIMA"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you implement the list open toggle?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Diogo , can you make a js fiddle with your current statut of code

Comment: @MoolsBytheway that's what you requested?
https://jsfiddle.net/83Leta9s/1/

Comment: @RubenPirotte It's opening like a popup list, after the button press.

Comment: I added them... don't know why it's not showing... ¬¬
They are:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css

Comment: ok found'em "external ressources"

Comment: @MoolsBytheway yep! (y) kkk

Comment: I believe had found the source of the problem, but not the cause... my own CSS code... Do not repair the mess kkk

https://jsfiddle.net/83Leta9s/4/

Comment: Checkout my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `#wrapper` `div`'s css :

```
div#wrapper {
 overflow:hidden;
 height:auto;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoolsBytheway/83Leta9s/5/)

Comment: You welcome, just check my answer as the right one and you can go x'D :)

Answer (score 0):

**Add Css**

```
select
{
  height:137px;
}
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/7zy31eLy/)

Comment: It will be applied just to the "hidden" list?

Comment: any issue my answer ??. add comment if your other issue required this topic

Comment: I tryed add the css param and the the result kept the same.